# Where can I download the iPad logo?

Tags: ipad, apple-inc

I'm updating our catalog and one of our products is available for the iPad.
I'm looking for the log for that. I've found "Made for iPad" but I'd like just simply "iPad".

Comment: What logo are you referring to? Where have you seen it? Have you looked at Apple's guidelines for the MFi logos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has published [trademark and product placement guidelines](http://www.apple.com/legal/trademark/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html). Unless you are a registered developer, you should contact Apple and they can assist with proper logos and artwork.

Comment: Ha! This quote, from the referenced page, is hilarious: “You **may not use an image of a real apple** or other variation of the Apple logo **for any purpose**.” The advice given in the above answer is sound, though.

Comment: I believe that fruit restriction comes from the agreement between Apple Records and Apple when they entered in a financial/legal contract on their respective trademarks. Pretty odd that it would be "passed on" to others co-marketing with Apple, Inc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to speak directly with Apple's Marketing, PR, and/or Legal departments about this. Just casually throwing around Apple trademarks (or, frankly, any trademarks you don't own) is likely to get you sued.

That said, Apple's PR site has [this page](http://www.apple.com/pr/products/) has a bunch of product images that appear to be for public consumption.

**You should still speak with someone at Apple Corporate about this.** To keep a trademark, under US law, a company must defend that trademark to avoid dilution. Don't get yourself and your company or organization on the wrong side of a lawsuit.

Comment: The link to Apple's PR photos at great, but most catalogs would be commercial use as opposed to editorial and you are correct that seeking permission is mandatory unless you've checked with your lawyer on the laws covering your activity.